# How to delete all documents in elasticsearch with logstash from a search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash to pass data to elasticsearch and I would like to know how to delete all documents.

I do this to remove those that come with id, but what I need now is to delete all documents that match a fixed value, for example Fixedfield = "Base1" regardless of whether the id that is obtained in jdbc input exists or not.

The idea is to delete all the documents where elasticsearch fixedField = "Base1" exists and insert the new documents that I get from the jdbc input, this way I avoid leaving documents that no longer exist in my source (jdbc input).
A more complete example

My document_id is formed: 001, 002, 003, etc.

My fixed field is made up of "Base1" for the three document_id

Any ideas?

```
input {
  jdbc {
  jdbc_driver_library => ""
  jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
  jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxx;databaseName=xxxx;"
  statement => "Select * from public.test"
  }
}

filter {
if [is_deleted] {
        mutate {    
            add_field => {
                "[@metadata][elasticsearch_action]" => "delete"
            }
        }
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "is_deleted","@version","@timestamp" ]
        }
    } else {
        mutate {    
            add_field => {
                "[@metadata][elasticsearch_action]" => "index"
            }
        }
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "is_deleted","@version","@timestamp" ]
        }
    } 
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "xxxxx"
    user => "xxxxx"
    password => "xxxxx"
    index => "xxxxx"
    document_type => "_doc"
    document_id => "%{id}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked like this:

```
output {  

    http {
                url => "http://localhost:9200/%{[@metadata][miEntidad]}/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed"
                http_method => "post"
                format => "message"
                content_type => "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
                message => '{"query": { "term": { "properties.code.keyword": "%{[properties][code]}"  } }}'

    }

    jdbc {
                connection_string => 'xxxxxxxx'       
                statement => ["UPDATE test SET estate = 'A' WHERE entidad = ? ","%{[@metadata][miEntidad]}"]   
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to eliminate, but ..... the problem I have now that apparently when the input starts, it counts the number of records it gets and when it continues towards the output, it eliminates in the first round and in The following n-1 turns the error message is displayed:

> [HTTP Output Failure] Encountered non-2xx HTTP code 409
>   {:response_code=>409,
>   :url=>"http://localhost:9200/my_index/_delete_by_query",

The other, which I think may be happening is that _delete_by_query is not a bulk bulk deletion, but rather query / delete, which would lead to the query returning n results and therefore trying to delete n times.

Any ideas how I could iterate it once or how to avoid that error?
I clarify that the error is not only displayed once, but the number of documents to be deleted is displayed n-1 times

```
input {
  jdbc {
  jdbc_driver_library => ""
  jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
  jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxx;databaseName=xxxx;"
  statement => "Select * from public.test"
  }
}



output {
   stdout { codec => json_lines }

  elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "%{[@metadata][miEntidad]}"
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][miDocumento]}"
        document_id => "%{id}"
  }


 http {
      url => "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_delete_by_query"
      http_method => "post"
      format => "message"
      content_type => "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      message => '{"query": { "term": { "properties.codigo.keyword": "TEX_FOR_SEARCH_AND_DELETE"  } }}'
  }
 }
```